# Can you edit php variables through the include method?

Tags: php, include

Is there a way to edit a variable from another php file through the include method? I'm trying to create a database file because actual databases aren't an option for me right now and I find this easier. Here's my code:

```
include 'database.php';
$new = array_slice($passwords,0,1);
$passwords = $new;
```

And the database.php file:

```
<?php
$usernames = array("first", "second");
$passwords = array("first", "second");
?>
```

I'm trying to remove the second username and password, but
It doesn't seem to work. Is there another way I could do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure it does.  Is the variable from the other file in a function?

Comment: If the variable in the other file is declared in the function it will only have the scope of that function and cannot be used outside that.

Comment: I made an edit that gives more information. What I'm trying to do is remove the second username and password from the database.

Comment: And no, it is not inside of a funcion (as seen above).